# Is sealing via tape necessary for knee wall foam board insulation.?

Tags: insulation, attic, ventilation

I have dramatically improved the ventilation and insulation situation in my house's knee wall attic space, but I have one concern.

I nailed up foam board over the studs and fiberglass batts.  Do the seams really need to be sealed with expanding foam or tape?  How much more performance would I gain?  If so, which is the better option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sealing the seams will not increase the R-value of the insulation.  However, sealing the seams is important as an air infiltration/moisture seal, preventing air from infiltrating  and, as a result, preventing moisture (condensation) from occurring between the foam board and batt. Typically expanding foam creates a better, longer-lasting seal than tape.

Comment: Agreed, but my concern would be air infiltration, not moisture. However, sealing it solves both.

Comment: Mazura, I agree with you 100%.  I really meant moisture as a result of air infiltration (aka condensation).

Comment: I'm not too concerned about moisture.  I have a vapor barrier on the backside of the drywall.  I am more concerned with making sure I get the best insulating performance out of the batts and the foam board.